# Spring JPA - @OneToOne/@MapsId - Parent/Child with shared key: I get this GenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: spring-data-jpa

When adding a parent and child with a **@OneToOne** relation having the same key, I keep on getting this error. It is advised to use @MapsId.

> **id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null**
>   **one-to-one property**

The usual solutions I tried, but that did not solve the problem.

- Having both parent and child point to each other
- The right Transactional (being springframework's)
- Saving using the owner's repo. This does not work because of the violation of a upper restriction.

My parent Entity is (with names having a purpose):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOHAN_SHARED_SUPPLIER")
public class EntitySharedSupplier {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "supplier_shared_id")
    private Long javaSharedSupplierId;

    @Column(name = "supplier_shared_name")
    private String javaSharedSupplierName;

    @Column(name = "contact_shared_name")
    private String javaSharedSupplierContactName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "supplierSharedRef", orphanRemoval = true)
    private EntitySharedProduct javaSharedProduct;
```

The child is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOHAN_SHARED_PRODUCTS")
public class EntitySharedProduct {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "shared_supplier_id")
    private Long javaSupplierSharedId;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="shared_supplier_id")
    private EntitySharedSupplier supplierSharedRef;

    @Column(name = "prod_supplier_name")
    private String javaSharedProductName;
```

The repo of the parent is:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SupplierSharedRepo extends JpaRepository<EntitySharedSupplier, Long> {
}
```

The service code:

```
@Transactional
public void saveSupplier(int sup) {
    EntitySharedSupplier supplier = new EntitySharedSupplier();
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierId((long) sup);
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierName("SharedSupplier-" + sup);
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierContactName("SharedSupplier-contact-" + sup);
    EntitySharedProduct product = new EntitySharedProduct();
    product.setJavaSharedProductName("SharedSupplier-Book-" + sup);
    product.setSupplierSharedRef(supplier);
    supplier.setJavaSharedProduct( product);
    supplierSharedRepo.save(supplier);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this case was a bit difficult.

The solution is by changing the set id/key method in the parent object:

```
public void setJavaSharedSupplierId(Long javaSupplierId) {
    this.javaSharedSupplierId = javaSupplierId;
    if( javaSharedProduct != null) {
        javaSharedProduct.setJavaSupplierSharedId( javaSupplierId);
    }
}
```

**NOTICE**:

- In most cases you have an **automatic id/key generation of the parent** at a late stage during the hibernate/jpa save process. At that moment the connection between parent and child is done already.
- In this case, the solution works because first the connection is made between parent and child and then the **manual id/key of the parent** is set.

Till then, I kept on getting either the original error (as shown in the question) or that the id of the id was not set.

The solution needs a small change in the creating of the parent/child objects.

```
@Transactional
public void saveSupplier(int sup) {
    EntitySharedSupplier supplier = new EntitySharedSupplier();
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierName("SharedSupplier-" + sup);
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierContactName("SharedSupplier-contact-" + sup);
    EntitySharedProduct product = new EntitySharedProduct();
    product.setJavaSharedProductName("SharedSupplier-Book-" + sup);
    product.setSupplierSharedRef(supplier);
    supplier.setJavaSharedProduct( product);
    // The next statement has to be put after the previous
    supplier.setJavaSharedSupplierId((long) sup);
    supplierSharedRepo.save(supplier);
}
```

The solution works and is easy to understand. I also have software that doesn't need this manual setting of the child id in the parent id. So far, I haven't tracked down why that software works.

**If you have a better solution, let me/us know!**